# Data Validation Warning Message with openxlsx Package in R: Sprintf

Tags: r, excel, validation, warnings

Basically, I am creating data validated excel spreadsheets for data entry purposes using R. The code seems to work however I get a warning message when I run the dataValidation functions. I am curious as to why Im getting this warning and if I need to change anything? Checking the package documentation everything seems to be correct but maybe Ive missed something. I have added some code below highlighting the process of making a workbook in r for excel.

```
#start workbook
wb2 <- createWorkbook()

# Add worksheet "SampleEntry" to the workbook
addWorksheet(wb2, "SampleEntry")

#add site data to the new workbook
writeData(wb2, sheet = "Sites", x = site_db$site_id, startCol = 1)

#use data validation on column 2 of the first page of workbook with site data
dataValidation(wb2, "SampleEntry", 
               cols = 2,
               rows = 2:10000,
               operator = "equal",
               type = "list",
               value = "'Sites'!$A:$A")
```

Warning message:
In sprintf("<x14:dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="%s" showInputMessage="%s" showErrorMessage="%s">",  :
one argument not used by format '<x14:dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="%s" showInputMessage="%s" showErrorMessage="%s">'

Comment: That's apparently an unresolved code issue when trying to validate against a list (`dataValidation(..., type = list)`): https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/342#issue-1200556672

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Almost forgot: although it's "only" a warning, please make sure that the validation indeed works for the workbook generated (as far as I understood the underlying code, the "unused argument" is part of the XML value specifying the [Excel] range the valid values are picked from).

Comment: Well actually that is why I asked, because for me it has been working but for a colleague I shared the code with it has not been working...I tweaked a few things in their code so hopefully it works now.